# Yii2 field accessed only via magic method

Tags: yii2, many-to-many

```
/**
 * This is the model class for table "hashtag".
 *
 * @property string $text
 *
 * @property TweetHashtag[] $tweetHashtags
 * @property Tweet[] $tweets
 */
class Hashtag extends ActiveRecord
{
.........
    public function getTweetHashtags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TweetHashtag::className(), ['hashtag_text' => 'text']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getTweets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tweet::className(), ['id' => 'tweet_id'])->viaTable('tweet_hashtag', ['hashtag_text' => 'text']);
    }
}
```

When I do in some component

```
   $hashtags = Hashtag::find()
                ->with('tweets')
                ->where(['text' => $hashtagText])
                ->all();

            foreach($hashtags as $hashtag)
            {
                print_r($hashtag->tweets);
            }
```

It`s working but why tweets - field accessed only via magic method and how can i fix it? And tweetHashtags working well.

Class Tweet have same relationship but `public function getHashtags()` working without this problem.

Comment: Do you have an error if you access to tweets-field not using magic method? Are all tweets fields accessible only from magic method?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. Each method on a `Component` class that start with `get` (like `getName`) can be accessed with property form (e.g. `name`). On special case, relations of Yii's `ActiveRecord`, if you access to relation by property form, you get results. In fact `$this->tweets` is a shorthand for `$this->getTweets()->all()`.

P.S: On Yii2 Document http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#accessing-relational-data:

> Note: While this concept looks similar to the object property feature,
>   there is an important difference. For normal object properties the
>   property value is of the same type as the defining getter method. A
>   relation method however returns an yii\db\ActiveQuery instance, while
>   accessing a relation property will either return a yii\db\ActiveRecord
>   instance or an array of these.
>
> ```
> $customer->orders; // is an array of `Order` objects
> $customer->getOrders(); // returns an ActiveQuery instance
> ```
>
> This is useful for creating customized queries, which is described in the next section.

Comment: this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-properties.html) should also be useful about how setters & getters are working in Yii.